# Let's make a huge number with only tiny numbers

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

**Using only three 1s and two 2s (i.e. 1,1,1,2,2), can you generate the number 55?** You can use all mathematical operators you know, such as floor function, factorial, powers/indices*, etc., but concatenation is not allowed (e.g. '11' from 1 and 1 is not permitted).

* Any powers used must be derived from the initial set of three 1s and two 2s - you don't get to use 'squared' (for example) without accounting for the '2' required when writing this as a formula.

Comment: 11*(1+2+2) feels natural

Comment: @Daniel "example, 11 from 1,1 is not allowed".

Comment: Without definitive constraints it seems it comes down to who makes the best looking solution

Comment: 55 is still small, not huge, I was expecting a use-case for tetration. Assuming we can use exp() as a function, I did it using only two numbers. Should we add a softpenalty to disincentivize esoteric stuff like double-factorial or Lambert W-function?

Comment: Is the "decimal point magic" mentioned below legit? I feel like using `.2` brings in an extra number, 10. Also, what about the `exp` function, which brings in `e`?

Comment: My intuition says that using floor or ceiling (even if it's explicitly allowed in the question) should be less elegant than "moderately esoteric" approaches like tetration or double factorial; it can do too much. Out of the approaches seen so far, I feel like binomial coefficients are the cleanest, and "decimal point magic" the second cleanest (because of the concern that $.2$ is really just short for the forbidden $0.2$, and also perilously close to concatenation).

Comment: Hey guys I am surprised no one mentioned this, but isn't this just straight copied from this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4788368/how-can-i-make-huge-numbers-with-only-tiny-numbers-i-have-to-make-55-with-1-1-1) on Math SE? Checking the timestamps indicate that this question has been posted about 3 hours after the one on Math SE was posted.

Comment: @AidenChow where they were advised to post the Q on Puzzling. Both are new contributors and perhaps the same person. I didn't see that page before posting my answer.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, I am aware they were advised to post of Puzzling SE because I was the one who advised them to do it lol. But I still think something should be done, maybe if they are the same person the accounts should be merged? And I feel like either the Math SE or Puzzling SE question has to be closed, they are basically the same question even if they are posted on different sites.

Comment: @AidenChow then I suggest you propose the other question be closed since you recommended posting it here. It would be perverse of you to recommend that and then say this question should be closed.

Comment: @WeatherVane Are we absolutely sure these two are the same person? I don't want to suggest closing the Math SE question just to find out later that they are actually two different people and that one copied the other.

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: @WeatherVane Well, is there any way to check? I feel like something should be done here, not just let this slide.

Comment: @AidenChow you could vote to close, with your stated reasons (a puzzle not a math problem; reposted on Puzzling) and see what happens.

Answer (score 31):

My answer is

> $ 55 = 1 + (1 + 2)!  + ((1 + 2)!)!! $
>
>  $ 55 = 1 + 3! + (3!)!! $
>  $ 55 = 1 + 6 + 6!! $
>  $ 55 = 7 + 48 $

---

Another solution, again with no concatentation

> $ 55 = \sqrt{(((1 + 2)!)!! + 1)} + ((1 + 2)!)!! $
>
>  $ 55 = \sqrt{((3!)!! + 1)} + (3!)!! $
>  $ 55 = \sqrt{(6!! + 1)} + 6!! $
>  $ 55 = \sqrt{(48 + 1)} + 48 $
>  $ 55 = 7 + 48 $

---

A solution using base 6, working in the other direction.

> $ 55 = 100 - 1 $
>  $ 55 = 10^2 - 1 $
>  $ 55 = 3!^2 - 1 $
>
>  $ 55 = (1 + 2)!^2 - 1^1 $

Comment: +1 for using base six. Lovely little loophole that

Comment: Aw shucks, I was going for the double factorial as well (+1)

Answer (score 28):

Using only addition, division, and decimal point magic, while preserving the order of the digits:

> $$\frac{1+\frac{1+1}{.2}}{.2}=\frac{11}{.2}=55$$

Or alternately, using some sillier operators and a nifty coincidence:

> $$ \sum_{n=1}^{(1+2)!} (n-1)^2 $$
>  $$ = 0 + 1 + 4 + 9 + 16 + 25 = 55 $$

Or utilising [combinatorics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination):

> $$ 1/.1 - 1 + 2 \choose{2} $$
> $$= 11 \text{ choose } 2 = 10+9+8+7+6+5+4+3+2+1 = 55$$

Or finally (always save the prettiest one for last), bringing in the notation $T_n$ for the *n*th [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number):

> $$T_{T_{1 \times 1 \times 1 \times 2 \times 2}} $$
>  $$=T_{T_4} = T_{10} = 55$$

which can (if you don't mind the slightly awkward MathJax layout) also be written using exponents for some further savings on ink (and/or pixels):

> $$T_{T_{2^{2^{1^{1^{1}}}}}}$$

Comment: Decimal point seems a bit magic. You're just bringing a 10 to the table. The ones NOT using decimal point are very clever.

Comment: If you're not allowed to make 11 from 1 and 1 I don't think you should be allowed to make .1 from 1. But +1 for the first and last examples, they're great.

Answer (score 22):

Since "indices" are allowed, how about we

> index into the Fibonacci numbers, with $F_{(1+1)(1+2+2)}$ giving us the $10^{\text{th}}$ Fibonacci number, $55$?

Comment: This one's a good one

Comment: I have heard rumors that some places, "indices" is mostly another name for exponents. Which makes sense given the context in which they are mentioned in the OP.

Answer (score 19):

Ends up with an approximation, but a handy ceiling function makes it legitimate.

> $\lceil(\sqrt{1+1}+(1+2)!)^2\rceil$

⸂⸂⸜(രᴗര๑)⸝⸃⸃ woohoo

Answer (score 12):

$-\log_2(\log_2(\sqrt(\sqrt(\sqrt(...\sqrt(1 + 1 * 1) ... )))))$

with 55 total square root signs.

Comment: Sneaky way to get all the 1/2's in.

Comment: +1 for an answer that generalises to other target values

Answer (score 9):

As a binomial coefficient

> $$\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt {((2+1)!-1)!+1} \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$$.

If we accept Donald Knuth's notation *n*? for the *n*-th triangular number this can also be written

> $$(1+2?)??$$

with a 2 and two 1s to spare.

Alternatively, here is one inspired by @Lynn's tetration:

> $$\sqrt{\sqrt{.2}^{-.1^{-1}}-.1^{-2}} = \sqrt{\sqrt 5^{10}-10^2} = \sqrt{3125-100} = 55$$

Last not least, as absolute value of a complex number:

> $$\left | ((2+1)!)!! + \sqrt{-((2+1)!)!-1} \right| = \left | 48 + \sqrt{721}\mathrm i \right | = \sqrt{48^2+721} = 55$$

If we use triangular numbers as above we can write more compactly:

> $$\left | 2??!! + \sqrt{-2??!-1} \right|$$

Answer (score 8):

Using one [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration):

> $$\left\lfloor \sqrt{^2 (1+1+1+2)} \right\rfloor = \lfloor \sqrt{5^5} \rfloor = \lfloor \sqrt{3125} \rfloor = \lfloor 55.901\dots \rfloor = 55.$$

Answer (score 5):

I tried using as few numbers as possible, which gave

> $ (\frac{2}{.2} + 1)!!!!!! $
>  $ = (10 + 1)!!!!!! $
>  $ = 11!!!!!! $
>  $ = 11 \times 5 $
>  $ = 55 $

We can also easily add the additional numbers to this with

> $ (\frac{2}{.2} + 1)!!!!!! + 1 - 1$

Comment: How is the operator '!' defined here? It does not appear to be the common definition of the factorial.

Comment: @xyldke the [multifactorial](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multifactorial.html) is essentially a factorial that skips numbers. For instance, the double factorial n!! = n(n-2)(n-4)... Here, the 6-th multifactorial would be n(n-6) = 11*5

Comment: I don't want to edit my post after the fact but I just realized $((2+2)!!)_{1+1}-1$ also works using both multifactorial & falling factorials and $(2+2)??$ works using triangular numbers since $T_4 = 10$ and $T_10 = 55$!

Answer (score 5):

Using only two of the digits!

> $\lceil \exp(2+2)  \rceil = \lceil 54.59815...  \rceil = 55 $
>
>  And you can consume the ones by doing
>  $ \times 1 \times 1 \times 1 $

Comment: I posted a similar answer before I realized you beat me to it! 

I would argue that exp counts since this can be written as $\lceil\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + \frac{2 + 2}{n})^n\rceil$ which still uses only one extra 1 in addition to the two 2s

Answer (score 4):

> $55 = 1 + \large \Bigl( \sqrt \frac{1}{.\overline{1}} \Bigr)! \times \frac{2}{.\overline{2}}$
>
>  where $.\overline{n}$ means $.nnnnn\cdots$

Comment: You need to apply floor to sqrt, otherwise you'd be using the non-integer generalization of factorial

Comment: @smci No, the repeating decimal makes it $\sqrt{\frac{1}{1/9}}=3$.

Comment: Ah, my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by ralphmerridew's answer, using only one digit, you can make any number:

> $\lceil-\ln(\ln(\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{...\sqrt{2}}}}))\rceil$
>
>  Where every square root increases the total by $\ln(2) = 0.693$
>
>  To make 55, use 78 sqrts.

---

Other solutions:

Using only 4 of the digits:

> $((1/.1)+1)/.2$
>
>  $= (10+1)/.2$
>  $= 11/.2$
>  $= 55$
>
>  If we want to use all 5, just change it slightly to this:
>
>  $(((2-1)/.1)+1)/.2$

Using 4 digits, without using decimal points:

> $\lceil\sqrt{(((2+1)!)!)}\rceil * 2 + 1$
>
>  $= \lceil\sqrt{6!}\rceil * 2 + 1$
>  $= \lceil\sqrt{720}\rceil * 2 + 1$
>  $= \lceil 26.8 \rceil * 2 + 1$
>  $= 27 * 2 + 1 = 55$
>
>  Or with 5 digits like this:
>
>  $\lceil\sqrt{1+(((2+1)!)!)}\rceil * 2 + 1$

Answer (score 1):

Using the generalized [multifactorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial#Generalizations), we can get the following

> $$((2+1)! + (2+1)! - 1)!!!!!! = 11 \times 5 = 55$$

Here's a slightly more convoluted answer using the floor function, the cotangent function and binomial coefficient

> $$\binom{-\lfloor \cot(2+1) \rfloor}{2+1} - 1 = 56 -1 = 55$$

Answer (score -5):

$(1+1)^3 - 1 + 2^4 + 2^5$

$= 2^3 - 1 + 2^4 + 2^5$

$= 8 - 1 + 16 + 32$

$= 7 + 16 + 32$

$= 7 + 48$

= 55

Comment: Here you're using a '3', a '4' and a '5' as powers without having accounted for them - these would need to be calculated using the original 1,1,1,2,2 as per the question specification.